# onclick event on checkbox in haml/rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I want to implement realtime events (google analytics) on our filter engine.

This is my code:

```
%fieldset
  .checkbox
    %input{type: "checkbox", value: ".range-1", :onclick=>"_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Price', 'Range 100-200', 'Yep']);" }
```

This is the html:

```
<div class='checkbox'>
 <input onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Price', 'Range 100-200', 'Yep']);" type='checkbox' value='.range-1'>
 <label>€</label>
```

This code don't work. What a i doing wrong here ?

thanks..remco

Comment: This isn't a Ruby on Rails question, it's about JavaScript, please update your tags. Do you get any console output?

Comment: Can you please verify that you are using classic GA? The onclick code seems to indicate that.